# How can I solve the "Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '{parent}'" error?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save the 'df' to 'dataset' file.

There is my code
The code file name is 'practice.py'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x1": [100000, 200000, 300000],
    "x2": [400000, 500000, 600000],
    "x3": [700000, 800000, 900000]},

     index=[2019, 2021, 2020]

)
df.index.name = 'year' # set the index name

df.to_csv('dataset/covid_dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8') # save to file
```

I think I set the file path well, but I don't know where the mistake is.

And this is my file structure :

[image]

Here is the error message :

```
(covid_project) C:\self_project\covid_project>C:/self_project/covid_project/Scripts/python.exe c:/self_project/covid_project/covid19_project/practice.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\self_project\covid_project\covid19_project\practice.py", line 13, in <module>
    df.to_csv('dataset/covid_dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\self_project\covid_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3563, in to_csv
    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
  File "C:\self_project\covid_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1180, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()
  File "C:\self_project\covid_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 241, in save
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\self_project\covid_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 697, in get_handle
    check_parent_directory(str(handle))
  File "C:\self_project\covid_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 571, in check_parent_directory
    raise OSError(fr"Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '{parent}'")
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: 'dataset'
```

Here's the desired result:

- I want to save 'df' as 'covid_dataset.csv' file name in 'dataset' file.

Comment: please add the error message text, not a screenshot of text

Comment: do some debugging ... do `df.to_csv('covid_dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8')` ... if no error is generated, then find out where the file saved

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machine
windows 11
python 3.8

try './dataset/covid_dataset.csv'